# Is there a way to sniff asynchronically in scapy?

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, python-asyncio, scapy

I'm making a project that uses scapy to scan a wi-fi network & check for attacks on the networks, i need a way to sniff the packets and send them to functions in multipule classes that will inspect the packets so i need the sniffing to be done asynchronically, the only problem is that python is not really thread-friendly...
so i need to find a way to take a packet and inspect it but keep sniffing in the same time

tried to use asyncio but i had too much errors and i just couldn't fix them.

Comment: "but i had too much errors and i just couldn't fix them"—please share your code and the errors. We can't help you fix code we can't see.

Comment: for this use case, the "thread unfriendly" aspect of Python does not apply - just use `threading.Thread` there and you are good: the S.O. will switch to your analysis code while the thread that waits for I/O on the network does so.

Comment: Otherwise, write a minimal, reproducible, friendly, example of what you want to achieve, enhance your question with it, just with a comment pointing `# I'd like to make this call work asynchronously`,  and you can get more concrete help here. It will probably be along keep the `scapy` calls in a thread of them own and run the analysis code in an asyncio loop in the main thread anyway.